# echo not working in a command

Tags: unix, command-line, aix

I run following command for log monitoring.

```
echo ---------------------BEGIN:0;awk ' NR == NR {print $0; recno=NR; rec=$0} END {printf "output is %010d>%s",recno, rec} ' "/var/log/messages";echo ;echo ------------------END:0;
```

The expected output is

```
Nov 12 03:36:52 hostname gdm[27726]: GDM already running. Aborting!
output is 0000028518>Nov 12 03:36:52 hostname gdm[27726]: GDM already running. Aborting!
---------------------END:0
```

But on one AIX 5.3 box(ksh) I get following output

```
Nov 12 03:36:52 hostname gdm[27726]: GDM already running. Aborting!
output is 0000028518>Nov 12 03:36:52 hostname gdm[27726]: GDM already running. Aborting!---------------------END:0
```

There is no "new line"  after "Aborting!" which should be there because of second last echo command.

This happens only on that particular box.
Can anybody please tell me why this is so?

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of Unix have an echo that outputs nothing, not even a newline, if it has no arguments. Might be AIX is one of these (I have never used so don't know). Do this instead:

```
echo ''
```

This tells echo to output an empty string, followed by a newline.

Comment: I checked that....but thats not the issue...there are some other commands similar to this....echo w/o argument is working fine...thats why i am stumped...it is failing for this particular command